# Type Member Layout Designer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

Does anyone know a GUI designer for Resharper's Type Member Layout? I find that editing the XML to satisfy my wishes is cumbersome. If no GUI designer exists, can someone give me pointers as to have the following order:

```
1. Properties
2. Constants / Static Readonly
3. Constructors
4. Methods
5. Interface Implementations
6. Nested Types
```

The secondary order should be:

```
1. Static > Instance
2. Public Internal Protected-Internal Protected Private
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This blog post should help: [In-depth look at customizing type layout with ReSharper](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/01/in-depth-look-at-customizing-type-layout-with-resharper/)

Comment: Thank you! @gorohoroh, do you know how to specify that types and delegates should be sorted alphabetically with a namespace. I have a file "Delegates.cs" with 50+ delegates and would like to have them sorted.

Comment: You should be able to add the <Sort><Name/></Sort> and that should do it.